# User input to control output

Tags: python, pandas

```
data['Year'] = input("Select a Year: ")
data['Month'] = input("Select a Month: ")

grouping = data.groupby(["Year", "Month"])

monthly_averages = grouping.aggregate({"Value":np.mean})

print(monthly_averages)
```

Guys - trying to pick a year, and a month, then show the mean value for that month. The last 3 lines alone will show every year and month average, but I want to be able to select one. New to python, not sure how to apply the choice to the grouping.

Comment: please provide the type of the "data" variable and the output of your print

Comment: You're modifying the dataframe in your `input()` calls. Is that what you really intended?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example table you can show us? Something like this *should* work but I can't test it without an example. I'd recommend reading up on the [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) method.

```py
year = input('Select a year: ')
month = input('Select a month: ')

df2 = data.loc['Year' == year]
df3 = df2.loc['Month' == month]

grouping = df3.groupby(["Year", "Month"])

monthly_averages = grouping.aggregate({"Value":np.mean})

print(monthly_averages)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need grouping if your picking one month and one year

`df[(df['Year'] == 'input_year') & (df['Month'] == 'input_month')].mean()`